# How to send body and multiple images to a rest API in ionic

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building a phone app with ionic, and I have a photo array that the user takes or loads from the gallery, like this:

```
this.camera.getPicture(options).then(imagePath =>  {
  this.imagen = imagePath;
  this.galeriaImg.push(this.imagen);
})
```

Now, I want that when I do the post to the server, which is a rest API in nodeJS, I can send the body and the images array in the same petition. I've been trying to do it with FileTransfer, but I can only send the images one by one, and I can't send a body with them. Does anyone know how this could be achieved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should grab everything and send as “multipart form” type to the node server. A quick google of that will show you how.